# Displaying custom field description on VF page

Tags: visualforce, visualforce-component, custom-field, metadata-api

I have a requirement where the names of the custom fields far exceed the 40 characters limit. So instead I thought I would put a keyword in the field name and the whole name in the description of the field. Is there possibly a way, to print the description of a field on the VF page? I could have done it manually too but the number of fields is close to 100 and making so many manual entries on the VF page isn't the best approach.

Someone please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the Description but it will require quite some digging into the metadata API. 
I'd suggest using the HelpText for this and replacing the label for a field by the helptext, which is available directly in VisualForce. E.g.:

```
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
    <apex:outputLabel value="{!$ObjectType.Account.fields.Street__c.InlineHelpText}"/>
    <apex:outputField value="{!a.Street__c}"/>
</apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
```

Comment: Actually I tried this approach. What itdid was, it rendered a help bubble which showed the help text (in this case my field description) when the cursor was hovered over it. I want the text to be displayed on the page at all times and not just when the cursor is hovered. Also, I read it somewhere that for the help bubble rendering, we have to put the showheader attribute to true. But I need it to be false since my page would be available on sites.

Comment: the difference is that I'm not using the helptext tag on pageblocksectionitem, but inserting only the text from the helptext into the outputlabel..

Comment: Oh yes! It works! thank you so much. You saved the day :-)